# Higher Dijkgraaf Witten Theory

Tags: homotopy-theory, mathematical-physics, higher-category-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

I am trying to understand higher form symmetries in TQFT. In particular the higher form version of Dijkgraaf Witten Theory.

It is know that for a 0-form symmetry we can specify the principal G-bundle through homotopy classes of the classyfing map
$$ M \rightarrow BG = K(G,1). $$
This is known from Homotopy Theory and Eilenberg-MacLan spaces. Indeed the homotopy classes of this maps are in bijection with the first cohomology group $H^1(M,G)$ that for a finite group is isomorphic to $Hom(\pi_1(M),G)$ and fit the usual gauge theory:
$$ [M,K(G,1)] \simeq H^1(M,G) \simeq Hom(\pi_1(M),G) $$

I cannot find any reference about higher version of this. Should I expect a naive generalization? This is motivated from the fact that for a 1-form symmetry $H^2(M,G)$ works as a straightforward generalization to the previous case. But does homotpy theory tell me something about classification of gerbes via classyfing maps?

Moreover the 2-Group approach works in a similar way, we introduce $K(G,2)$ and stuff.

But how should I formulate this for a single 1-form symmetry? I hope I was clear, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the generalization is the most straightforward that you can imagine. In $d$ space-time dimensions, the $p-$form untwisted Dijkgraaf-Witten theory for an abelian finite group $G$ is just a sum over $G$ $(p+1)-$forms connections, which you define as homotopy classes of maps $M_d \rightarrow K(G,p+1)$. This Eilenberg-MacLane space is defined by the property that $\pi _{p+1} (K(G,p+1))=G$, while all the other homotopy groups are vanishing. Thus homotopy classes of maps $\phi : M_d\rightarrow K(G,p+1)$ are completely characterized by group homomorphisms
\begin{equation}
hol \ , \pi _{p+1}(M_d) \rightarrow G
\end{equation}
which are the holonomies of the gauge field along the $p+1$ dimensional cycles. These characterize completely the $G-$bundle. Indeed one can prove that, as in $p=0$ case, $[M_d, K(G,p+1)]\cong H^{p+1}(M_d,G)$.

You can also generalize this to the twisted case. For $p=0$ this amounts to choose a group-cohomology class $\omega \in H^d(BG,U(1))$ and perform the sum weighted by a phase, which is the integral over $M_d$ of $\phi ^* \omega \in H^d(M_d,U(1))$. In the higher $p$ case you cannot use group-cohomology but you can still pick a characteristic class $\omega \in H^d(K(G,p+1),U(1))$ and do the same.